# How do I modify a configuration file using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a cfg file. In that cfg file there is a line like:

```
[Environment]
automation_type=GFX   ;available options: GEM, HEXAII
```

I want to modify this line by:

```
[Environment]
automation_type=ABC   ;available options: GEM, HEXAII
```

I have written the below code for this:

```
get_path_for_od_cfg = r"C:\Users\marahama\Desktop\Abdur\abc_MainReleaseFolder\OD\od\odConfig.cfg"
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read(get_path_for_OpenDebug_cfg)
    for sec in config.sections():
        for attr in config.options(sec):
            if sec =='Environment' and attr == 'automation_type':
                config.set('Environment','automation_type','ABC')
    with open(get_path_for_OpenDebug_cfg, 'wb') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)
```

After executing the code, I get

```
[Environment]
automation_type = ABC
```

---

```
";available options: GEM, HEXAII" this line is missing.
```

Comment: That line is a comment. I don't think `RawConfigParser` objects store comments.

Comment: this is because ";available options: GEM, HEXAII" is a comment. I think you should either move the comments to another line, or use simple text-processing techniques, instead of ConfigParser.

Answer (score 6):

As the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/09811ecd5df1/Lib/ConfigParser.py) suggests, when reading config files, comments are ignored, both those on separate lines ([484](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/09811ecd5df1/Lib/ConfigParser.py#l484))...

```
if line.strip() == '' or line[0] in '#;':
     continue
```

and on option lines ([522](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/09811ecd5df1/Lib/ConfigParser.py#l522)):

```
if vi in ('=', ':') and ';' in optval:
     # ';' is a comment delimiter only if it follows
     # a spacing character
     pos = optval.find(';')
     if pos != -1 and optval[pos-1].isspace():
         optval = optval[:pos]
```

So I agree with the comment above saying that you should switch to something more low-level if you care about preserving comments.